# How can I Format the strings into specific formats

Tags: php, string, string-formatting

I have some SQL fields which I need to show as the heading of the table in PHP

Following are some of my fields names and I want to show them as Following strings

```
    market_name =>Market Name
 company_name => Company Name 
company_address => Company Address 
operating_hours => Operating hours
```

Is there any String Formatting option in there ?

Comment: Why this Question was Negatively Voted?? I really needed the answer.. And I thank all of you who have replied to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `ucwords()` and `str_replace()` to produce the required result:

**Code:**

```
$strings = array('market_name', 'company_name', 'company_address', 'operating_hours');
foreach($strings as $string){
$string = ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $string));
echo $string."<br>";
}
```

**Output:**

```
Market Name
Company Name
Company Address
Operating Hours
```

Documentation: [**`ucwords()`**](http://php.net/ucwords), [**`str_replace()`**](http://php.net/str_replace)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$string = "market_name";
//replace the underscore with whitespace
$step1 = str_replace("_", " ", $string);
//capitalize the words
$step2 = ucwords($step1);
//this will give you
Market Name
```